Записать строку, закодированную алгоритмом Хаффмана, в бинарный файл на C++
У меня есть готовый алгоритм Хаффмана, он правильно переводит исходную строку в строку из нулей и единиц. Как записать эту строку в бинарный файл?

Допустим, ваша строка находится в переменной str
string str = "010001010";

ofstream out(“TEXT.txt”,ios::binary|ios::out); 
out.write((char*)str.c_str(),str.length()+1);
out.close(); 

Однако настоятельно рекомендую сделать так:
string str = "010001010";
size_t ln = str.length()+1;

ofstream out(“TEXT.txt”,ios::binary|ios::out);
out.write((char*)&ln,sizeof(ln));
out.write((char*)str.c_str(),ln);
out.close(); 

Чтобы потом можно было считать файл, не запоминая, какой длины у вас была строка.
istream in(“TEXT.txt”,ios::binary|ios::in);
size_t ln;
in.read((char*)&ln, sizeof(ln));  
char * buf = new char[ln];
in.read(buf,ln);
string str = buf;
delete[] buf
in.close();


Вместо первого с тем же успехом можно просто написать out << str;. Я думаю, что у автора вопроса проблема не в записи строки как таковой, а в приведении ее в бинарный вид, где 8 символов строки превращаются в один байт.

Записывать сжатые данные текстом, увеличивая объём в восемь раз, такое себе.
